# Study the injectivity and surjectivity of a complex function

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $h:\{z ∈ \mathbb{C}| Re(z) < 0\} \to \mathbb{C}$
such that $h(z)=z^2$. Determine if $h$ is surjective and/or injective and also find $h^{-1}(D)$ where $D=\{z ∈ C| |z|<=1\}$.

I have this as my first homework for university. Nobody that I asked in my year knows how to do it.

P.S. I am a CS student.

Comment: Have you tried anything (even if you could not make progress)? What is your background on complex valued functions, and functions overall? Providing context is always appreciated and contributes to answers that will suit you better.

Comment: I think that the h^(-1)(D) can be solved with the trigonometric form of the complex numbers, besides this, I don't really have any good ideas.

Comment: I was just about to suggest that, for the first part of the problem. Maybe it will also help re-writing the domain as $\{re^{i\pi\theta}: \theta\in(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}), r\in(0, +\infty)\}$ and recalling that $(re^{i\pi\theta})^2 = r^2e^{2i\pi\theta}$ (the geometric intuition for this is that squaring a complex number squares its modulus and also "rotates it" by its original argument. To check for injectivity: can you get the same modulus and argument twice, for different adequate $r$, $\theta$? And to check for surjectivity, can you get purely imaginary numbers from this operation?

Comment: What is the $C$ in $D = \left\{ z \in C \mid |z| \leq 1 \right\}$? Is it the set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ or another set?

Comment: @KevinDietrich Complex numbers, yeah.